# Set value of text area and have it register a change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area:

```
<input id="startdate" name="startdate" type="text" value="" style="width:23%">
```

that listens to on('change')`

```
$('#startdate').on('change', function () {
  var $formelem = $(this);
  // DO SOME WORK
  ... 
});
```

and the code to change the value of the text area:

```
var keyval = location.search.replace('?', '').charAt(0);
  var filterDates;
  var clicked = [];

  function persistence(keyval) {
    function template(keyval, filterDates) {
      for ( i=0 ; i < keyval.length ; i++ ) {
        $('#'+keyval[i]).click();
      };
      if (filterDates) {
        return $('#startdate').val(filterDates);
      };
    };
    if (typeof parseInt(keyval[0]) === 'number' && keyval[0] % 1 == 0) {
      switch(keyval[0])
        {
        case '1': 
          keyval = ['.', '..', '...' ];
          filterDates = "2006-04";
          template(keyval, filterDates);
          break;
        case '2': 
          keyval = ['.', '..', '...' ]; 
          break;
        default:
          template(keyval);
        };
    } else {
      template(keyval);
    }
  };
```

When the page loads, if the url contains a `1`, then I want to change the value of the textarea to `2006-04` AND have it register a change, so that the change function occurs.   Currently the text is getting updated, but the function is not running.   I think it might have something to do with the page not being loaded, so I placed it in the document.ready(), and it is still not working.   Anything else I am missing?  The [API](http://api.jquery.com/val/) doesn't mention anything about having to attach an event handler to it, so I thought that the on('change') would do the trick.....

Also, if I manually change it, the function does do the work it is supposed to do, so its not the code in the function.   Also does the fact that I dynamically set the initial value elsewhere have anything to do with it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    blinks(1);
    persistence(keyval);
});
```

and

```
//place the first value of start[] in the startdate box
$('#startdate').val(start[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *trigger* a *change* by using:

```
$('#startdate').trigger('change');
```